# How do you configure Google Tag Manager with Taleo?

Tags: google-tag-manager, taleo

I have been doing a lot of searching around online and have been surprised at the lack of resources on this subject considering the popularity of both Oracle's Taleo and Google Tag Manager.

The Oracle support team insisted we needed to have a phone call to walk through this process because they do not document it in their "Resource Centre".

Hopefully these instructions will help you avoid that phone call.

Answer (score 0):

Once logged into the Business Edition Area, click on 'Administration' in the top right.

Click on the 'Customize Recruit' tile.

Under the Manage Careers Websites area, click on the 'Header & Footer' link under your respective Website area (if you have more than one).

You can now paste your GTM code into the `<head>` and `<body>` tags as instructed by Google.